# Why can't I declare a pure virtual function with `= delete;`?

Tags: c++, c++11

### Intro

Pure virtual functions are delcared with the common syntax :

```
virtual f() = 0;
```

Yet, since c++11 there's a way to communicate the explicit `non existence` of a (special) member function :

```
Mystruct() = delete; // eg default constructor
```

### Q

Why isn't this syntax extended to pure virtual functions in order to achieve uniformity in communicating such operations ? :

```
virtual f() = delete;
```

### Note

I know the obvious answer is `because the Standard says so!`. I'm wondering about the reason(ing) behind this and whether there ever was a proposal (or an intention) for something like this.

Comment: `virtual ~MyStruct() = delete;` is already taken and acts very differently.

Comment: @chris Yep, strong point. Even if there was the intention, there can't be an implementation.

Comment: `= delete` is already permitted on non-special member functions (including virtual functions) and non-member functions, and means "a call to this function is a compile-time error"

Comment: Keep in mind that the syntax `virtual f() = 0` has no reasoning behind it either. According to Bjarne Stroustrup, he saw no chance of getting a new keyword accepted at the time

Comment: Strictly speaking, `virtual f() = 0` can't actually compile because we can't have a pure virtual constructor.  It would have to have a type in there somewhere for it to not be a constructor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`= delete;` means something entirely different from making a function pure virtual. Unlike deleted functions, a pure virtual function does not make ill-formed a program that selects it as the result of overload resolution.

Comment: `does not make ill-formed a program that selects it` Since there can't be instances of abstract classes a pure virtual function can never be selected after overload resolution

Comment: `abstract_class* a = new derived_class; a->pure_virtual_function();`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I don't think that overload resolution is going to choose `pure_virtual_function()` of base class.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes This example is exactly what I meant. Is dynamic dispatching considered a step after overload resolution ? Because from a high level always the implementation in derived classes is chosen.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou:  Dynamic dispatch occurs at runtime, based on whichever object is actually being used at that time.  Overload resolution occurs at compile time.

Comment: @DaveS So overload resolution actually chooses the function in the base class (the pure virtual function) and then the "correct" function is invoked. Yes, ofcourse makes sense

Comment: @DaveS Thnx for the info. I [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24960909/2567683) a follow up q on this (mainly on "then why explicitly resolving the function breaks compilation)

Comment: @40two there's no other function to choose. Consider `void f(abstract_class& a) { a.pure_virtual_function(); }`. At the time overload resolution takes place, `derived_class` need not even exist.

Answer (score 13):

Roughly speaking, the difference is that this:

```
virtual void f() = 0;
```

says "This class is *abstract*, and I may not have written an implementation of this member function" (though you are allowed to).

However, this:

```
void f() = delete;
```

says "This member function literally does not exist, and *none shall pass*."

Comment: I never have used this `delete` notation and I'm curious what advantage it confers over simply not defining a function. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Logicrat: It's useful for copy constructors and such. If you simply do not declare a copy constructor then, in some/many circumstances, one is declared for you. You have to mark it as `private` in order to prevent its use, and then the compile errors are not terribly clear. _`=delete` documents intent and improves diagnostics._

Comment: Are there cases where I would use `delete` on regular functions, not operators? In [this Godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/WEnf3zPjo), does class A make any sense? Class C doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 7):

There is a big difference in what the two things mean.  Roughly speaking, the difference is that this:

```
virtual void f() = 0;
```

says "I may have not written an implementation of this function."

However this:

```
f() = delete;
```

says "Attention compiler: do not create an implementation of this function."

Comment: The latter says even more! It also says "if you find me trying to use this, punish me for I have been a very naughty boy".

Comment: The former does not mean that at all. It is perfectly valid to produce a definition for a pure virtual function. See my answer for _the Truth_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The intent was to convey a rough approximation to aid in comprehension rather than quoting chapter and verse from the standard.  With that said, I rather like R. Martinho Fernandes explanation for `delete`.

Comment: @Edward: Well if by "convey a rough approximation" you really mean "propagate a dangerous and popular misconception" then you're doing a great job! Instead, aid in comprehension by telling the truth; by telling non-truths you are actually _hurting_ comprehension (which should be self-evident).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I will leave *the Truth* to those who feel they have a monopoly on it.  I only offer an answer which may or may not be useful to the person who asks a question.

Comment: @Edward: I'm telling you right now that it will not be useful. They may or may not be misled into thinking that it will be. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few automatically generated member functions: default constructor, destructor, copy-constructor, assignment and there are some new move constructors too.

The purpose of being able to `delete` them is to ensure the compiler will not allow them to be invoked. The old trick was to declare them `private` and not give them an implementation.

This was cumbersome to do, but significantly it did not completely block calling them as a friend class (or even the class itself) might accidentally invoke a copy or assignment and although you would get a linker error, it is not ideal as you cannot see where the error is, and really you want a compiler error.

Declaring a function as virtual with `=0` does not prevent it from being called. It has a special meaning in making your class abstract so you cannot create an instance, and means that the function does not need an implementation, but it has a different meaning to deleting it.